# Using Apple's TouchCell example, how can I create a UIBarButtonItem item if one or more cells are checked?

Tags: iphone, ios

The tableview is populated from a .plist.
I want to be create an "ADD" button on the navBar if one or more cells are checked and remove the "ADD" button once all of the cells are unchecked.  The best I've been able to do is add the button when a cell is checked and remove the button when the cell is unchecked but this is not taking into account that other cells may have a checkmark in them.  If any cell is in the table has a checkmark, the "ADD" button should be present. 
The example code I'm working with can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TouchCells/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008062

In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, I've added:

```
if (targetCustomCell.checked)
{

UIBarButtonItem *saveButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(add)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButtonItem;
}
else
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

I'm including the DidSelectRowAtIndexPath for reference:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// find the cell being touched and update its checked/unchecked image
CustomCell *targetCustomCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[targetCustomCell checkAction:nil];

// don't keep the table selection
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

// update our data source array with the new checked state
NSMutableDictionary *selectedItem = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[selectedItem setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:targetCustomCell.checked] forKey:@"checked"];
}
```

Thank you for any help - it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

```
// first check the check box value
// if selected then add object
if (checkbox.selected) {
 [self.dataArray addObject: <get your object using button tag match with row no>];
}

// if deselected then remove that object
else {
 [self.dataArray removeObject: <get your object using button tag match with row no>];
}


// check the array count
// if > 0 then add bar button
if ([self.dataArray count] > 0) {
 UIBarButtonItem *saveButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(add)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButtonItem;
}

// if = 0 then remove bar button
else {
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your code you are having one selector method ***add***.

So in that method check

```
if ([self.dataArray count] > 0) {
 UIBarButtonItem *saveButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(add)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButtonItem;
}
else {
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Hope this code will work for you.

Let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Using: if ([self.dataArray count] > 0) didn't work.  The nav button gets created but we never hit the else statement because the dataArray will never be 0. I just want the nav bar button to show if any row has a check mark and disappear when none of the rows contain a check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help!
My solution to this issue was to add the below code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
BOOL hasChecked = NO;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.count; ++i) 
    {
         NSDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
         BOOL isChecked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
         if (isChecked)
         {
            hasChecked = YES;
         }

    }
if (hasChecked)
{

    UIBarButtonItem *saveButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" 
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                                      target:self 
                                                                      action:@selector(add)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButtonItem;
    [saveButtonItem release];

}
else
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```